# Operation for a new column with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a new column based on a condition from another one. 
For example: 
I want to calculate a 'Discounted price' column based on the event. Say if 'Poetry' apply 10% discount, if 'Theater' apply 15% discount, else, return normal price.

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# Creating the DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'], 
                    'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theater', 'Comedy'], 
                    'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000]}) 

# Create a new column 'Discounted_Price' after applying 
# 10% discount on the existing 'Cost' column. 

df['Discounted_Price'] = df['Cost'] - (0.1 * df['Cost'])
```

In my head, it would be something like (disregard the syntax):

```
df['Discounted_Price'] = if(df['Event']== 'Poetry') then df['Cost']*0.9,
                         elif (df['Event']== 'Theater') then df['Cost']*0.85
```

and so on.

Any advice on how to do this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

df:

```
       Date     Event   Cost
0   10/2/2011   Music   10000
1   11/2/2011   Poetry  5000
2   12/2/2011   Theater 15000
3   13/2/2011   Comedy  2000
```

you can also use `np.where` to satisfy all needs in one line

```
df['Discounted_Price'] = np.where(df.Event == 'Poetry', df['Cost']*0.9, 
                       np.where(df.Event == 'Theater', df['Cost']*0.85, df['Cost']))
```

Now output is:

```
       Date     Event   Cost    Discounted_Price
0   10/2/2011   Music   10000   10000.0
1   11/2/2011   Poetry  5000    4500.0
2   12/2/2011   Theater 15000   12750.0
3   13/2/2011   Comedy  2000    2000.0
```

So, it fulfills the `else` requirement and instead of getting `NaNs`, you get all costs

```
df.loc[df['Event']=='Poetry','Discounted_Price']=df['Cost']*0.9
df.loc[df['Event']=='Theater','Discounted_Price']=df['Cost']*0.85
```

Output:

```
        Date    Event   Cost    Discounted_Price
0   10/2/2011   Music   10000   NaN
1   11/2/2011   Poetry  5000    4500.0
2   12/2/2011   Theater 15000   12750.0
3   13/2/2011   Comedy  2000    NaN
```

**Edit**

You can also use select(as suggested by @sammmywammy), to solve the problem on hand.
I have designed following statements that can help you in solving multiple conditions on multiple columns as well.

```
conditions = [
    (df['Event'] == 'Music'),
    (df['Event'] == 'Theater'),
    (df['Event'] == 'Poetry'),
    (df['Event'] == 'Comedy')]
choices = [(df['Cost']*0.9),(df['Cost']*0.85),(df['Cost']*0.7), (df['Cost']*0.5)]

df['Discounted'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='null')
```

for single calculation on multiple columns transform above query as

```
conditions = [
    (df['Event'] == 'Music'),
    ((df['Event'] == 'Theater') | (df['Event'] == 'Comedy')),
    (df['Event'] == 'Poetry')]

choices = [(df['Cost']*0.9),(df['Cost']*0.85),(df['Cost']*0.7), ]

df['Discounted'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='null')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer M_S_N!

In the case that I would need to group multiple 'Events' for one operation, how would that look like (using np.where)

Comment: you mean this `df['Discounted_Price'] = np.where(df.Event == 'Poetry', df['Cost']*0.9, 
                       np.where(df.Event == 'Theater', df['Cost']*0.85, np.where(df.Event == 'Comedy', df['Cost']*0.85 df['Cost'])))`

Comment: same operation for `Theater` and `Comedy`

Comment: you can increase nested `np.where` in the above statement or you can create a function and apply it to `df`

Comment: Any recommendations for the function? I am still learning the basics

Comment: You can have a look at NumPy select, it certainly covers multiple and nested conditions and could make your code syntax cleaner and clearer